# SQLite blob data validation / testing

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, blob

I am creating tests for an SQLite data base with a blob data type. I would like to validate blob (byte array - picture).

This is what i have and right now I am not checking PICTURES_COLUMN which causes an error (blob cant be parsed to String).

Comparing Set made from ContentValues to a cursor:

```
  public void testHotelSingleInsert() {
        SQLiteDatabase testDb = testDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long testRowId;

        ContentValues testContentValues = TestUtils.getSingleContentValue(testContext);
        testRowId = testDb.insert(HotelsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, testContentValues);

        assertTrue("Error: single insert to hotel table failed", testRowId != -1L);

        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> testSet = testContentValues.valueSet();
        Cursor cursor = testDb.query(HotelsEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : testSet) {
            String columnName = entry.getKey();
            int columnId = cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName);

            if (entry.getKey().toString() != HotelsEntry.PICTURES_COLUMN) {
                assertEquals(
                        "Value: " + entry.getValue().toString() + " is not equal to: " + cursor.getString(columnId),
                        entry.getValue().toString(),
                        cursor.getString(columnId));
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I validate that blob in a professional way? Do I have treat blob separetly and get it out of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

To get all values out of a row, use [cursorRowToContentValues()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#cursorRowToContentValues%28android.database.Cursor,%20android.content.ContentValues%29).
To compare two `ContentValues` objects, use [equals()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: This doesn't necessarily convert return Blob type in the ContentValues result and might cause trigger:
`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Unable to convert BLOB to string`

Comment: @MichaelLee `SQLiteCursor` acually is derived from `AbstractWindowedCursor`.

Answer (score 0):

`cursorRowToContentValues()` doesn't necessarily work.

the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java) for `cursorRowToContentValues()` shows that only when `Cursor` is an instance of `AbstractWindowedCursor`, then would Blob be return.

Even when it does return a byte array data from Blob instance to the ContentValues, `equals()` in ContentValues will show the two byte arrays not equal.

I recommend either know which columns are BLOB and validate them separately. Or do something like this:
`entry.getValue().getClass().equals(byte[].class)` to check `Array.equals((byte[]) entry.getValue(), cursor.getBlob)`